# What are alternatives or metaphors for the idiom of discovering a "gold mine"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, metaphors, emotions

The context I am writing in is along the lines of: When we can identify and appreciate our emotions, we are able to carefully engage both emotion and cognition in the decision making process which makes it a "very valuable" destination point when we are able to get to that stage.

I'd like to use an idiom to describe this "very valuable destination point", the best I've come up with so far is discovering a gold mine:

> When you are able to use your knowledge to transform your feelings into a positive and productive force, *you will have found a gold mine*.

Is there a more common idiom that would work here? Is there one that would fit better within the context of emotions?

Comment: What does discovering a gold mine have to do with navigating emotions?

Comment: @JasonBassford The context I am writing in is along the lines of: When we can identify and appreciate our emotions, we are able to carefully engage both emotion and cognition in the decision making process which makes it a "very valuable" destination point when we are able to get to that stage.

Comment: Suppose, if there is a suitable idiom, how you are going to use it in a sentence. Can you provide an example sentence with a dash?

Comment: Your question should indicate what basic research you've performed, for example thesaurus searches on *valuable.*

Comment: Thank you. Suppose if I were to use the idiom "gold mine", it would be:
_When you are able to use your knowledge to transform your feelings into a positive and productive force, you will have found a gold mine._

Comment: Any other variations which convey the same meaning are welcome, but using a metaphor or idiom of some sort is a must. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

**to strike gold** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79763?redirectedFrom=strike%20gold#eid44317005) idiom in the figurative

> (fig.) to find (a source of) great profit or **success**.

As in:

> When you are able to use your knowledge to transform your feelings
>   into a positive and productive force, you will have **struck gold**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a more common idiom than "finding a gold mine" is **[hitting the mother lode](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hit-the-mother-lode)**:

> <sup>informal</sup> to produce or find something that will make you very rich, happy, or successful: *They hit the mother lode with their second album.*

<sup>Longman dictionary</sup>

The **[mother lode](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mother%20lode)** is:

> the place where the largest amount of gold, silver, etc., in a particular area can be found

<sup>Merriam-Webster</sup>

So it's analogous to your "discover a gold mine", but in my experience it's more idiomatic.

*Note: I'd tend to spell it **motherlode** as one word, but all serious references I can find spell it as two separate words.*

Comment: There's also "struck/strike oil", which has the same connotation as "finding the mother lode", just with a different valuable substance.

Comment: @pboss3010 - Good one. Worth a separate answer IMO (I'd upvote it).

Answer (score 0):

To leave the mining metaphors behind, we could use a more broad idiom:

**Clear road**: [Item 3](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/clear)
Free of any obstructions or unwanted objects.
‘with a clear road ahead he shifted into high gear’

(The above clear road/high gear can be figurative or not)

> When you are able to use your knowledge to transform your feelings into a positive and productive force, you will have found a **clear road ahead**.